# NoClassDefFoundError while running Roboelectric Unit Test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am trying to run a Roboelectric Unit test to test if the intended activity is getting started or not, but as I'm getting the following error :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   android.os.AsyncTask

I am looking for the solution but no luck so far, Has anyone faced this issue before.

**Find below my Test class**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml", minSdk = 21, maxSdk = 21, application = MyApplication.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
public class PushManagerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldLaunchNewActivity() throws Exception {
    Activity testActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(TestActivity.class);

    Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(testActivity, NewActivity.class);
    Intent actualIntent = ShadowApplication.getInstance().getNextStartedActivity();
    assertEquals(expectedIntent.getComponent(), actualIntent.getComponent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `PowerMock`?

Comment: For running some other test, it is not relevant to this test case, but I need it to run other tests in my suite

Comment: So is it problem for all tests or only for this one?

Comment: No only for this particular test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally fixed it, dont know if it is the correct way or nor but the tests are working as expected

I had to add the following lines in the `onCreate` of my Application class

```
try{
    Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
}catch(Throwable ignore) {
        // ignored
}
```

Hope it helps someone